# Differential: Smoothness

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

*This is a lemma for another thread.*

Given smooth manifolds.

The differential is a smooth map:
$$F:M\to N:\quad F\text{ smooth}\implies\mathrm{d}F\text{ smooth}$$
How to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

Regard its coordinate representation:
$$\widehat{\mathrm{d}F}(\hat{x})v=(\hat{F}(\hat{x}),\mathrm{J}\hat{F}(\hat{x})v)$$
This is clearly smooth.